# Where do I find the libraries to reference for SCOM?

Tags: c#, scom

This must be more simple than I am making it...
I have been tasked by my company to write an application that will query the SCOM data warehouse. We are using SCOM 2007 R2.
I know this can be done from readings online, but when I try to create an application (using C# in VS 2013), I add the using clauses:

```
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common;
```

and EnterpriseManagement remains in red (Cannot resolve symbol 'EnterpriseManagement'). Ok, so I need to add a reference; but from where?
I have checked all locations available in VS (Assemblies & COM) and I have even gone so far as to install the System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2 Authoring Resource Kit; but I cannot find the library (or libraries) that need to be referenced.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

Comment: Get `Operations Manager 2007 R2 SDK` from here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee533840.aspx

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky: That seems like a logical place to get it from, but I cannot find an option to download the kit on that page nor on any of the pages linked from there :-(

Comment: They come with `Microsoft System Center` and you can get more info here : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/DownloadResults.aspx?q=system%20center

Comment: Thanks anyway. Nothing useful there either. I am however looking into getting MSSC from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The DLLs are installed with the Operations Manager console in the `SDK Binaries` directory, or you can take them from an Operations Manager server, e.g. `C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\SDK Binaries\`.